# Django core: <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at ....> is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, django, serialization

I'm using Django 1.8 and in some of my code I just do:

```
self.request.session['message'] = [
    _(u'Tag!'),
    _(u'Abt!'),
    _(u'Click here to hide this message')]
```

Then when the page refreshed I have this problem:

```
<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x04805F70> is not JSON serializable
```

Of course I've googled for it, and I've read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/#session-serialization) which says that "JSON supports only string keys" and "the JSON serializer from django.core.signing Can only serialize basic data types".

Unless I'm wrong, arrays made of strings are basic data types. Moreover that code has been there for 6 months without a problem.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is `_`? `ugettext` or `ugettext_lazy`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that what you are trying to serialise are not strings - they are [lazy translation objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#translated-strings) (i.e. strings marked for translation, that has not been evaluated yet).

Most likely there is a line in the same file similar to this one:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

to use a translation function that is not lazy (i.e. it returns translated strings and not lazy translation objects) you should change it to:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
```

Alternatively you can force evaluation of lazy translation objects before serialising them by calling `str()` on them.

Comment: Thank you very much I found the error when I saw your answer!

Comment: Not a problem. BTW, have you looked at the [Django's built-in messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/)? It seems you are doing something very similar by hand.

Comment: Omg... Django: batteries included. I was a Php expert 2 years ago and you always had to do everything by hand. That's why I'm doing my best to explain why student should run away from Php... And I've done a lot by hand like that in Django, discovering some time after that everything was built-in...

Comment: After reading the documentation, I've done almost exaclty what they've done (my system is session-based). Thank you for the link!

Comment: i spent haft day to fix this error, you save my day :)